# Getting Error saying "JNI DETECTED Error in application" in Pixel 3

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have added 64 Bit Libraries mentioned by IBM in https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2019/05/24/Google-Play-64-bit-requirement/

But getting error when launching App in Pixel 3 with Android 9 and trying to initialise JSON Store.

I am using MFP 7.1 for this.

Note: This App completely works fine if i remove library files for 64 bit from jniLibs.

2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeHandle" in class "Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;" or its superclasses
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:-2)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1014)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1669)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(android.content.Context, java.io.File) (SQLiteDatabase.java:177)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(android.content.Context) (SQLiteDatabase.java:170)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.openDatabaseIfNecessary(android.content.Context) (DatabaseManager.java:181)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at boolean com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.checkDatabaseAgainstSchema(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema) (DatabaseManager.java:100)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at boolean com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema.isSchemaMismatched(java.lang.String, com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema, android.content.Context) (DatabaseSchema.java:417)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at boolean com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.provisionDatabase(com.worklight.jsonstore.api.JSONStoreCollection, com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String, int) (WLJSONStore.java:153)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.openCollections(java.util.List, com.worklight.jsonstore.api.JSONStoreInitOptions) (WLJSONStore.java:361)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at org.apache.cordova.PluginResult com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.initializeCollection(com.worklight.jsonstore.api.JSONStoreCollection, com.worklight.jsonstore.api.JSONStoreInitOptions) (ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:152)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at org.apache.cordova.PluginResult com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.types.JSONStoreContext) (ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:138)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at org.apache.cordova.PluginResult com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.types.JSONStoreContext) (BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at org.apache.cordova.PluginResult com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(org.json.JSONArray) (BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run() (DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542] 
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]     in call to FindClass
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542] "pool-7-thread-1" prio=5 tid=42 Runnable
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13140000 self=0x73da314c00
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=23688 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73d9bf94f0
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 339022707 806147 70 ) utm=31 stm=2 core=4 HZ=100
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0x73d9af6000-0x73d9af8000 stackSize=1041KB
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #00 pc 00000000003b62c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #01 pc 0000000000480f80  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #02 pc 00000000002df788  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+952)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #03 pc 00000000002dfb80  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+116)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #04 pc 00000000000fbd18  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+144)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #05 pc 00000000000fa6dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType)+1156)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #06 pc 00000000000f9a50  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType*)+628)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #07 pc 00000000000e17c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+772)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #08 pc 00000000001d658c  /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/lib/arm64/libsqlcipher.so (sqlcipher::register_android_database_SQLiteCompiledSql(_JNIEnv*)+36)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #09 pc 00000000001d71e4  /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/lib/arm64/libsqlcipher.so (JNI_OnLoad+196)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #10 pc 00000000002e31e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator> const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator>*)+2408)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #11 pc 0000000000004038  /system/lib64/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+412)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #12 pc 0000000000114bc8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 114000) (java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad [DEDUPED]+200)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #13 pc 0000000000545e4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #14 pc 00000000000cf6b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #15 pc 000000000027a978  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #16 pc 00000000002749b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #17 pc 0000000000516d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #18 pc 0000000000538314  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #19 pc 00000000000c6c36  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+38)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #20 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #21 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #22 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #23 pc 0000000000515830  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+588)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #24 pc 0000000000538194  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #25 pc 00000000000c9560  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.lang.System.loadLibrary+16)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #26 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #27 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #28 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #29 pc 0000000000516d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #30 pc 0000000000538314  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #31 pc 0000000000380baa  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs+10)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #32 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #33 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #34 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #35 pc 0000000000516d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #36 pc 0000000000538314  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #37 pc 0000000000380b72  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs+14)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #38 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #39 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #40 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #41 pc 0000000000516d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #42 pc 0000000000538314  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #43 pc 0000000000323444  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.openDatabaseIfNecessary+16)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #44 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #45 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #46 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #47 pc 0000000000516b64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #48 pc 0000000000538294  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #49 pc 0000000000322f8e  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.AMBMobileApp-bDD1Z-MzZGHfeX1aldLWlw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk (deleted) (com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.checkDatabaseAgainstSchema+2)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #50 pc 000000000024e938  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.953976685+488)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #51 pc 0000000000254098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #52 pc 000000000027499c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #53 pc 0000000000515830  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+588)
2019-08-12 17:53:21.435 23572-23688/com.AMBMobileApp A/om.AMBMobileAp: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #54 pc 0000000000538194  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)

I tried adding below values in proguard but seems no use.

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.* { *; }[image]

Comment: Which specific iFix version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: i.What is the ifix version you are using ?
ii.Is it issue specific on Pixel 3 ? or any other 64-bit devices ?
iii.Is it Native Android or Hybrid app ?

Comment: You might end up in this error if you have not replaced sqlcipher.jar

Comment: I am using 7.1.0.00.20190704-0841. Its a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line in gradle file has fixed my issue.

sourceSets { main { jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] } }